# Trouble parsing xml with jQuery on a extension for google chrome

Tags: jquery, xml, google-chrome-extension

I really can't figure out, what's wrong with this code:

This is my manifest.json file:

```
    {
     "name": "Test!",
     "version": "1.0",
     "description": "Testing this",
     "content_scripts": [ {
       "js": [ "jquery-1.4.2.min.js", "parser.js" ],
       "matches": [ "file:///*/*" ]
      } ],
     "permissions": [
       "tabs", 
       "http://*/*"
     ]
   }
```

Here is parser.js file

```
var xmlcontent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><A><B><C>Hey</C></B></A>";
var doc = $(xmlcontent).find('C').text();
```

This simple script, throws the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I also had lots of troubles with XML. Try switching between `text()` and `html()`

Comment: The problem is, that the error is thrown before it gets to text(), actually the problem is that $(xmlcontent) is null

Answer (score 0):

This works for me here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9mPM/

Are you sure you have access to jQuery from this environment?

Comment: I have just copied the source directly from jquery's website in the same file that the previous code, and now it throws an other error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of null. This time the error comes from jquery code.

Comment: Hmm...OK try something simple instead. Try: `alert($.toString());`. I don't think it will reveal much, but I'm curious.

Comment: output: function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)}

Comment: Blast...as I suspected nothing appears to be wrong. Try this one: `$('<a><b></b></a>').html()`. I'm beginning to wonder if it's because `.text()` searches for HTML text nodes, but I could be wrong.

Comment: output: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

Comment: OK, try something even simpler: `$.trim('test    ')`. Basically I want to see what *does* work in the jQuery core.

Comment: I've been trying changing the version of jquery, and the 1.2.6 doesn't throw errors, but it doesn't find the element either =S

Comment: I think the problem is that when jquery loads, as the current page is actually a XML file it tries to do some dom stuff that it cant.

Comment: I'm guessing it's got something to do with that as well. I'm having no luck finding anything, and I'm currently at work, so I'm not in a position to mess around with Chrome extensions (though, I suppose, this is as good an excuse as any to try it out). Please let me know if you find the solution..I'm very curious!